# Checking if a line was already drawn in matplotlib and deleting it

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I would like to know if there is a way to delete an line already plotted using matplotlib. But here is the thing:

I'm plotting within a for loop, and I would like to check before plotting if the line that I'm about to draw is already on the figure, and if so, I would like to delete it.

I was told an idea about plotting it anyways but with the same color of the background, but again, to do this I would have to check if the line already exists. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea how to do this?

- During iteration, before *making* a new line

  - check if x and y coordinates of the new line are the same as any of the lines already contained in the plot's Axes..

---

Comment: That's a solution, yeah, but wouldn't be a problem for memory? Imagine I have to draw 1000 lines, isn't it a memory problem? It's an honest question, I'm just curious

Comment: How would it be a memory problem - the lines already exist in memory the container just  has a reference to them. They are already contained in the plot's Axes so maybe just use that, see edit.

Comment: You're totally right mate, thanks @wwii, I solve it

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of @wii, I wrote this function which worked perfectly

```
def check_repeated_lines(x,y,ax,colors):
lines = ax.get_lines()  
bol = False
for i in range(len(lines)):
    x_i = lines[i].get_data()[0]
    y_i = lines[i].get_data()[1]

    if array_equal(x_i,x) == True and array_equal(y_i,y) == True:
        bol = True
        break
    else:
        pass

if bol == True:
    ax.lines.remove(lines[i])
else:
    ax.plot(x,y, linestyle = '-', color = colors, linewidth = 0.5)
```